# Hide non linked text in string using CSS

Tags: css, copy, hide, show

```
<div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="/page1/">Page 1</a> &raquo; page 2</div>
```

This is similar to the code I am using (I have just simplified it). This produces the following:

[Home](http:///) » [Page 1](http:///page1/) » page 2

Assuming we are on page 2, my end goal is to strip back the breadcrumb links on a responsive template so when viewed on a mobile device the breadcrumb only shows the parent page link:

Page 1     *this should be a link but I don't have the reputation yet

I can use the following to hide the 'home' link using:

> a {display:none;}
>
> a:last-child {display:inline;}

But I wondered if I can hide all text (2x »', 'page 2') within the div tag and then show ‹a› content?

Comment: I have changed the breadcrumb to an unordered list as I have more control over the element both in terms of Jquery manipulation and CSS styling

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can encapsulate the text you want to hide on small devices in `span` elements and adds them the class `hidden-xs` if you use bootstrap. Otherwise, you can add this class and write it by your own:

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
     .hidden-xs {
         display: none;
     }
 }
```

This way, the elements having this class will be hidden on small devices (you can set another value than the `768px` value).

Comment: encapsulate using Jquery (for example)?
I use the process on another part of my site but I just wondered if it was purely possible in CSS

Comment: I don't understand your question. The piece of code I wrote is in CSS, you don't need Javascript / Jquery to do it.

Comment: Sorry Killian, what I meant was by following your code I would have to go back and apply  .hidden-xs classes to all element I want hidden within my breadcrumb class, So I was asking if you were implying to use Jquery (and perhap Regular expression) to apply hidden-xe spans around the elements based on the media size automatically

Comment: Since the "»" are not encapsulated in any span / div, I can't figure out how to do it using jquery. You could iterate through `a` children of the `breadcumb` element and apply the `hidden-xs` style, but it would still skip the "»"...

Comment: Well there is actually a solution, which is not something that I would do but anyway. You can add the `hidden-xs` class with `$('.breadcrumb').addClass('hidden-xs')` and then force the last link to show up with `$('.breadcrumb a:last-child').addClass('always-show')`, the `always-show` class being `.always-show { display: inline-block !important; }`. This is only if you really don't want to put your hands into your HTML code, and I would personally don't use the `!important` hack but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> But I wondered if I can hide all text (2x »', 'page 2') within the div
>   tag and then show ‹a› content?

If I right understand it can left only links:

```
.breadcrumb{
    visibility: hidden;
}
a{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cva6wtbc/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cva6wtbc/2/

This shows how it would work on page 2 but as you can see the text is still pushing the visible text away from the left of the screen

Comment: Because it can show all link and hide all non-linked text. There isn't selector for different part of text inside one div.
You have two ways:
1. Add span to every non-linked elements;
2. Parse it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.breadcrumb a:after {
    content:'\00BB';
    position:absolute;
    right:-20px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.breadcrumb a {
    margin-right:30px;
    position:relative;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    display:none; /* in media query */
}
.breadcrumb1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-24px; /* - to hide the text */
}
.breadcrumb1 a {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>use » directly for a tag if you have created it manually
</p>

<div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a><a href="/page1/">Page 1</a>page 2</div>

<p>or you can use text-indent -ve value to hide the text
</p>

<div class="breadcrumb1"><a href="/">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="/page1/">Page 1</a> &raquo; page 2</div>
```